revalidatePath() and Video Uploading in Next.js
My medialibrary is not visually updating after I upload a video. I made a medialibrary for Images and Videos.
When I upload a ImageUrl in my supabase db, it directly shows (using cloudinary to generate the url). But when I upload a video, I first create a entry because the video needs to be processed by mux.
The first entry shows immediately then I listen with my webhook when the video is ready and update the video data. This update doesn't show in the ui only when I refresh.
I tried to use revalidatePath() to empty the cache but it doesn't seem to work. (revalidatePath will also not rerender the page if I understand correctly).
Maybe the (dashboard) in the path is making problems for the revalidatePath? Anyone tips how I can solve this?
I know i can solve this problem with polling but i want to use the server side way.
Here is my path: app/(dashboard)/[storeId]/media/page.tsx
Here is my server component that passes data so I can render the videos:
import PageContainer from '@/components/layout/page-container'
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma'
import VideoPlayer from './_components/video-player'
import Images from './_components/images'
import FileUploader from '@/components/file-uploader'
import Heading from '@/components/layout/heading'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default async function ProjectPage() {
  const images = await prisma.image.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc'
    }
  })

  const videos = await prisma.video.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc'
    }
  })

  console.log('Fetched Images:', images)
  console.log('Fetched Videos:', videos)

  return (
    <PageContainer scrollable={true}>
      <Heading title="Media" description="Upload and view images and videos" />
      <div className="p-4">
        <FileUploader />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
        <h3 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Images</h3>
        {images.length > 0 ? (
          <Images data={images} />
        ) : (
          <div className="flex justify-center p-4">No Images uploaded yet</div>
        )}

        <h3 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Videos</h3>
        {videos.length > 0 ? (
          <VideoPlayer data={videos} />
        ) : (
          <div className="flex justify-center p-4">No Videos uploaded yet</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </PageContainer>
  )
}

Here is my client component where I display my videos:
I'm just rendering the status for testing purpose. we are making the video ready displays after entry but it doesn't change to ready.
'use client'

import Icon from '@/components/icon'
import { AlertModal } from '@/components/modals/alert-modal'
import { Video, VideoStatus } from '@prisma/client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { toast } from 'sonner'

interface VideoPlayerProps {
  data: Video[]
}

export default function VideoPlayer({ data }: VideoPlayerProps) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [selectedVideoId, setSelectedVideoId] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [selectedAssetId, setSelectedAssetId] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set the mounted state to true after the component mounts
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])

  const handleDeleteVideo = async () => {
    if (!selectedVideoId || !selectedAssetId) return

    setLoading(true)
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/mux/delete`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ videoId: selectedVideoId, assetId: selectedAssetId })
      })

      if (response.ok) {
        toast('Video deleted successfully')
        router.refresh()
        setOpen(false)
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to delete the video')
        toast('Failed to delete the video')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
      setSelectedVideoId(null)
      setSelectedAssetId(null)
    }
  }

  const openDeleteModal = (videoId: string, assetId: string) => {
    setSelectedVideoId(videoId)
    setSelectedAssetId(assetId)
    setOpen(true)
  }

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null // Skip rendering until after the component has mounted
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AlertModal
        title="Are you sure?"
        description="This action can't be undone"
        isOpen={open}
        loading={loading}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={handleDeleteVideo}
      />
      <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
        {data.map((video) => (
          <div key={video.id} className="relative">
            <div className="relative h-60 w-60 rounded-md">
              {video.status === VideoStatus.processing ? <p>We are making the video ready</p> : <p>{video.status}</p>}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

Here is my mux handler:
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { createVideo } from './actions/create-video'

export const uploadToMux = async (files: File[], storeId: string | string[]) => {
  const uploadPromises = files.map(async (file) => {
    const identifier = uuidv4()

    const response = await fetch('/api/mux/url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ identifier })
    })
    const { muxUploadUrl } = await response.json()

    if (!muxUploadUrl) {
      throw new Error('Failed to retrieve Mux upload URL')
    }

    // Upload each video file to the corresponding Mux URL
    const uploadResponse = await fetch(muxUploadUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type
      },
      body: file
    })

    if (!uploadResponse.ok) throw new Error('Upload failed')

    await createVideo(storeId as string, identifier)

    console.log('Upload successful:', file.name)
    console.log('Upload response:', uploadResponse)

    return { status: uploadResponse.status, fileName: file.name }
  })

  // Wait for all videos to be uploaded
  const results = await Promise.all(uploadPromises)

  return results
}


Here is my webhook:
// next
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

// actions
import { updateVideo } from '@/lib/actions/update-video'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json()
  const { type, data } = body

  try {
    if (type === 'video.asset.ready') {
      const assetId = data.id as string
      const videoId = data.playback_ids[0].id as string
      const identifier = data.passthrough as string
      await updateVideo(assetId, videoId, identifier)
      console.log('Video updated')
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'ok' })
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to update video' }, { status: 500 })
  }
}

Here is my server action for creating the video:
'use server'

import prisma from '@/lib/prisma'
import { VideoStatus } from '@prisma/client'

export async function createVideo(storeId: string, identifier: string) {
  try {
    await prisma.video.create({
      data: {
        storeId,
        assetId: '',
        identifier,
        playbackId: '',
        status: VideoStatus.processing
      }
    })
    console.log('Video created in the database')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating video:', error)
    throw new Error('Failed to create video')
  }
}

Here is my server action for updating the video data:
'use server'

import prisma from '@/lib/prisma'
import { VideoStatus } from '@prisma/client'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

export async function updateVideo(assetId: string, videoId: string, identifier: string) {
  try {
    const existingVideo = await prisma.video.findUnique({
      where: { identifier }
    })

    if (!existingVideo) {
      throw new Error(`Video with identifier ${identifier} not found`)
    }

    await prisma.video.update({
      where: { identifier: identifier },
      data: {
        playbackId: videoId,
        assetId: assetId,
        status: VideoStatus.ready,
        updatedAt: new Date()
      }
    })

    console.log('Video updated in the database')

    // Revalidate the path after video is updated
    revalidatePath(`/${existingVideo.storeId}/media`, 'layout')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating video:', error)
    throw new Error('Failed to update video')
  }
}

